# How to get text from searchview?

Tags: android, text, searchview

How can I get the text from Searchview in this case
this is Search method

```
public void search(String query){
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(),contactOps.searchCursor(query));
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and this is Searchview Listener, when I put `searchview.query()`.toString in search method the application cracked ,How can I solve this problem ?

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            search(searchView.getQuery().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: please show your XML for Searchview and error log

Comment: I deleted the code to define the search view take the xml and convert it to java code by mistake,because that the app stopped,I solved the problem 
thank to all  of you

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        search(newText);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Instead

```
search(searchView.getQuery().toString());
```

Comment: Can you share what error your getting in your logcat

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: This error because ur not initialized `SearchView` properly...Can you share complete code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it check this

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the text from the searchView it's basically the **newText** from the method **onQueryTextChange**.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        //newText is the query you are searching 
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way to get string from searchview:

```
searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if(newText.length() >= 1){
                search(newText);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: the application stopped and this is the error in logcat

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
       //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.
         return true;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        //This is your adapter that will be filtered
        return false;
    }
});
```